# How can I resume a broken SFTP download in Window 7 console?

Tags: windows, putty, scp, sftp, pscp

In my Windows 7 console, I can download file from SFTP with the command

```
d://putty//pscp -P 22 root@serverip:/root/movie   c://movie
```

How can I resume a broken download in Window 7 cmd console when the file is very large?
Can `pscp` resume a broken download in Windows 7 cmd console?

Comment: Is the `psftp` command of any use to you? I've never used it but noticed it has a `reget` command.

Comment: Btw, Why are you using // instead of \ in Windows paths?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `pscp` does not support resume.

As @PeterJ commented, another tool from PuTTY suite, the `psftp`, does. You should have no problems resuming interrupted `pscp` transfer with `psftp`:

```
C:\>d:\putty\psftp root@serverip
psftp> reget /root/movie C:\movie
reget: restarting at file position xxxxxx
remote:/root/movie => local:C:\movie
```

Comment: Just adding `psftp` uses the SSH2 protocol, so it doesn't require a FTP server, as I originally thought when I saw its name.